# Custom TCP service vs HTTP IOS

Tags: ios, tcp, firewall

I am implementing a client (IOS device) and Server. I wish to keep the payload of request/responses to a minimum so plan to implement a custom TCP based service. My only concern is if I can rely on the port I use being always open through 3G etc. There must be other apps that use non standard ports and TCPon IOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can, you might use Port 80/443(SSL) for your custom TCP server. You only have to ensure that your have a free IP on your Server to bind your custom server-application to port 80.
If it's not HTTP(D) behind port 80/443(SSL), thats not a problem!

When using other port you may run into problems with blocked traffic in firewall rules.
But that's the standard case. Like a VOIP/SIP iOS App needs the SIP Port 5090. So if you are try to make a call within your University WiFi where only some Ports except 5090 are supported, the app won't run/connect.

So. You should make it like [Viber](http://itunes.apple.com/ch/app/viber-free-phone-calls-text/id382617920?mt=8) or [WhatsApp Messenger](http://www.whatsapp.com/) does. Use Port 80/443(SSL) and try to get the max possible connects trough possible firewalls.

Comment: Server is not a problem, look like 443 is a good option. Thanks